# Misunderstood python yield

Tags: python, generator, yield

This code below works correct :

```
def file_gen(f_name):
    f = open(f_name)
    for line in f:
        yield line

gen_line = file_gen("foo.html")
gen_line.next() # '<!DOCTYPE>\n'
gen_line.next() # '<html> \n' 
gen_line.next() # ... next line in file
```

But this function raises `StopIteration`. I don't understand why ?

```
def file_gen(f_name):
    f = open(f_name)
    line = f.readline()
    yield line

gen_line = file_gen('foo.html')
gen_line.next()  # '<!DOCTYPE>\n'
gen_line.next()  # StopIteration
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen?

Comment: The second one is actually a syntax error in Python (you cannot indent the `yield` line)

Comment: @6502 sorry , i corrected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have:

```
def file_gen(f_name):
    f = open(f_name)
    line = f.readline()
    yield line
```

Notice `line = f.readline()` This only reads 1 line from the file.

Compare:

```
def g(x):
    li=range(x)
    yield li.pop()

print list(g(10))
# [9]
```

with this:

```
def g(x):
    li=range(x)
    while li:
       yield li.pop()

print list(g(10))
# [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

`yield` can only be called once with a particular object or expression. Once it is used by the receiver it must be regenerated. So you need a loop around reading each line of the file.

You can use your second (less readable) form this way:

```
def file_gen(f_name):
    f = open(f_name)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        yield line
```

You need a loop to create the the items to yield. In your first case, `for line in f: yield line` is a loop.

I would rewrite your function this way:

```
def file_gen(f_name):
    with open(f_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

Comment: @A.M.Sultanov: Because `line = f.readline()` only reads 1 line. You need to wrap that in some form of a loop -- either a `while` loop of a more readable `for` loop

Comment: Or more specifically, you only call `yield` once, so the next call to `next()` hits the end of the generator.

Comment: @chepner: Yes -- that is a better way to state it.

Answer (score 2):

You get StopIteration on the second next() because you've only yielded one result. Did you mean to do this instead?

```
def file_gen(f_name):
    f = open(f_name)
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        yield line
```

Answer (score 1):

doesn't

```
line = f.readline()
```

only give you one line to yield? therefore iteration stops after that...

Comment: but if use this form: file = open('foo.html')  file.readline() file.readline() ... it  doesn't stop on the second line

Comment: When I try that it just gives me the second line instead of the first, then stops iteration on successive next() calls, as I would expect. Anyhow, seems like you've got to the bottom of your issue...

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**

```
def text_lines(path):
   textFile = open(path, "r")
   while True:
      line = textFile.readline()
      if line :
         yield line.strip()
      else:
         break
   textFile.close()
```